# Unable to download completed envelope pdf using dcousign rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to access signed envelop using REST API and I getting response from REST API but when I save the response to pdf, it doesn't show any content.

Below is a small python code that I wrote to achieve this.

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[Account ID]/envelopes/[Envelope ID]/documents/1"
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>[username]</Username><Password>[password]</Password><IntegratorKey>[Integrator Key]</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>'}
Response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

file = open("agreement.pdf", "w")
file.write(Response.text.encode('UTF-8'))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using httplib2, also the content is always going to come back formatted as a PDF through DocuSign, so I don't think you need to set the encoding.

```py
import json
import requests
import httplib2

url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[Account ID]/envelopes/[Envelope ID]/documents/1"
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>[username]</Username><Password>[password]</Password><IntegratorKey>[Integrator Key]</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>'}
http = httplib2.Http();
response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers = headers)
status = response.get('status');
if (status != '200'):
    print("Error: " % status); sys.exit();

file = open("agreement.pdf", "w")
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried using httplib2. I still only get header in my pdf. The entire agreement content and signature is missing.

Comment: can you post what is coming back in your http.request ?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post entire content. I provided the entire information to docusign enterprise support. Please engage them for the full response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the DocuSign API Walkthroughs?  These are accessible through the Developer Center, I suggest you take a look as there are code samples for 9 common API use-cases, each written in Python (and 5 other languages), including the 6th walkthrough which shows you how to query and download docs from completed envelopes.

The main problem with your code is that it's assuming the response only contains the document data, which is not correct.  The response will have headers and a body, that's why you can't render your document when you simply write it all to a file.

I suggest you use httplib2, which is what the following Python sample uses:
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeDocuments

Here is a snippet of the Python code but check out the above link for full code:

```py
#
# STEP 2 - Get Envelope Document(s) Info and Download Documents
#

# append envelopeUri to baseURL and use in the request
url = baseUrl + envelopeUri + "/documents";
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticateStr, 'Accept': 'application/json'};
http = httplib2.Http();
response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers=headers);
status = response.get('status');
if (status != '200'): 
    print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); sys.exit();
data = json.loads(content);

envelopeDocs = data.get('envelopeDocuments');
uriList = [];
for docs in envelopeDocs:
    # print document info
    uriList.append(docs.get("uri"));
    print("Document Name = %s, Uri = %s" % (docs.get("name"), uriList[len(uriList)-1]));

    # download each document
    url = baseUrl + uriList[len(uriList)-1];
    headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticateStr};
    http = httplib2.Http();
    response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers=headers);
    status = response.get('status');
    if (status != '200'): 
        print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); sys.exit();
    fileName = "doc_" + str(len(uriList)) + ".pdf";
    file = open(fileName, 'w');
    file.write(content);
    file.close();

print ("\nDone downloading document(s)!\n");
```

Comment: Thanks. I went through API walkthrough and a sample code from developer center. Now I just get header inside pdf. Entire agreement and signatures are missing from agreement pdf.

Comment: Are you running the Python API walkthrough or running your own version of the code?  The walkthrough should work "out of the box" (besides the variables you change at the top)